# Different appearance in VBA produced sheet with same font and cell attributes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the preparation of an internal Excel-based report based on a previous template.
The macro creates and fills a new sheet, matching the font name, size, color etc. settings of the template, as well as the row heights - column widths. Despite providing the exact same values for font, height, width etc., the VBA produced sheet's font does not match the original template. I believe the issue can be fixed if we can figure out why the VBA produced text is "pixelated".

As I am not familiar with the file sharing best-practices of SO, I will be including code used to reproduce the new sheet and a comparison of some attributes of the both sheets. I will include a link to the file containing the two sheets in the comments. I believe it may be important to have a copy of the original template to answer this question.

[image: Original template appearance][image: VBA produced appearance]

Here is an example of how a cell's properties are changed, pretty basic.

```
ws.Columns(12).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 9.57
ws.Rows(9).EntireRow.RowHeight = 50.25
ws.Cells(9, 12).Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
ws.Cells(9, 12).Font.Size = 11
```

Here are some properties I compared for the two sheets as I did not know what I was looking for, all are identical for the two sheets.

```
Range.AddIndent = False
Range.ColumnWidth = 9.57
Range.RowHeight = 50.25
Range.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
Range.Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
Range.Font.Size = 11
Range.Font.ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
Range.Font.ThemeColor = 2
Range.Font.OutlineFont = False
Range.Font.Subscript = False
Range.Font.Superscript = False
Range.Font.Italic = False
Range.HasSpill = False
Range.Phonetics = Nothing
Range.PrefixCharacter = ""
Range.SpillingToRange = Nothing
Range.UseStandardHeight = True
Range.UseStandardWidth = False
Range.WrapText = True

Worksheet.Cells.AddIndent = False
Worksheet.EnableOutlining = False
Worksheet.Outline.AutomaticStyles = False
Worksheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 18 'These are different, but did not effect the outcome when equalized
Worksheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 50.4 'These are different, but did not effect the outcome when equalized
Worksheet.PageSetup.FooterMargin = 21.6 'These are equal for both
Worksheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = 21.6 'These are equal for both
Worksheet.StandardHeight = 16.5 'These are different, yet read-only
Worksheet.StandardWidth = 8.38 'These are different, yet read-only
```

I know a little HTML/CSS and my guess is despite having the same font families(names), the .woff2 or .eot are different for the two fonts. I have no idea why though.

Painting the target cells using the original template format does the job, as does a copy/pasting strategy, but I am aiming for a clean solution without including the template in the final file and generating the sheets from scratch. I could also change the font family or cell sizes to get an acceptable output, but at this point I wish to explore the reason behind this issue out of curiosity.

Comment: https://github.com/volkansendemir/stackoverflow/blob/main/Same_Font_Different_Appearance.xlsm for the file

Comment: Woudn't it be easier to copy the template sheet completely?

Comment: At this point I am just trying to match the styles as best as I can, the template sheet will not be present in the continuation of the project. It is not even a requirement that the styles be a "perfect match", I am just curious about what might be causing the discrepancy and how to fix it. But you are right copy/pasting is a possible solution I might resort to unless I fix it another way first.

Comment: Store the template in the workbook where your code lives. Don't Copy&Paste the content of the sheet, copy the whole sheet. The worksheet object has a method `Copy` and with that you can create a copy of it, either into the same workbook or into another

Comment: I understand what you mean but I think it is not best-practice as it would involve the not-in-use original template sheet being present (and possibly accessible) in the final product. It feels unprofessional if the client has to see that additional sheet. Hiding it (xlVeryHidden) is also an option but does not satisfy my curiosity on the issue. I just want to know why this is causing an issue in the first place.